# Jquery mobile 1.4.3 popup doens't work in cloned page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to swicth from JQM 1.3.2 to 1.4.3, and I encounter a weird problem.

My home page displays a list of links to others pages. Those page are dynamically generated by cloning a master page. And those pages contains a button that should open a popup. It works fine with JQM 1.3.2, and not with JQM 1.4.3.

It looks like elements are not correctly enhanced after the cloning. But I tried the new enhanceWithin() function with no success. I tried also the popup() function.

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>JQM 1.3.2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#pagemaster">Master</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#pageclone" class="clone">Clone</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="pagemaster">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide">Back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#mypopup" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Open Popup</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="mypopup">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Popup</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">This popup is working correctly</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $(".clone").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#pagemaster").clone().appendTo("body").attr("id", "pageclone");
        $.mobile.changePage("#pageclone");
    });
});
```

Here is the working fiddle with JQM 1.3.2 : http://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/EsZ4F/1/

And here is a non-working fiddle with JQM 1.4.3 : http://jsfiddle.net/matthieubrunet/xrfAf/

If you click on the master link, the popup button will work, but not if you click on the clone link.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you try cloning data and events with `clone(true)`?

Comment: I just did, and it doesn't work…

Comment: I believe this may be caused by `<div data-role="popup" id="mypopup">`. You are not modifying that id in the clone, so you end up with two elements with the same id, which is never good.

Comment: Yes ! I added `$("#pageclone").find(".popup_button").attr("href", "#mypopup-clone");
        $("#pageclone").find("#mypopup").attr("id", "mypopup-clone");`and it worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question to close it, as Frédéric Hamidi gave me the solution in the comments :
I just need to update my id's to that they remain unique, and it work !

Note that I had a similar case with controlgroups, but this time, it was because I was calling the page() function after the clone(). This was necessary with 1.3, but not anymore with 1.4.